# I have an Error compiling Tensor Flow Lite example "Hello_World" for Rasperry Pi PICO

Tags: c, tensorflow, raspberry-pi-pico

The example "Hello_World" for TensorFlow Lite for RaspBerry Pi Pico in "https://github.com/raspberrypi/pico-tflmicro", but it does not compile.

All the Pi Pico examples are compiled without problems with Visual Studio.

I have the same problem and errors under Windows and RaspBerry Pi 4

I added an extra path in the c_cpp_properties.json file "/home/pi/pico/github/tensorflow/pico-tflmicro-main/"  and it did not work.

The error is The C compiler "/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc-7.3.1"
is not able to compile a simple test program.

Comment: Solution found already, here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=306406 (From the link, You need to "generate the files for CMake")

Comment: Hello,
     Thanks for your comment.

     I did cmake, with the command Clear Buffers and rebuild in Visual Studio Code.   

    I added a lot of folders and I having problems with the "INCLUDE files ERROR" althought they are in the "includePath": under Visual Studio Code.

     I'm continue testing different options. 

Thanks
Carlos

Comment: One solution was to compile ALL the examples in the folder. 

"pico-tflmicro-main"

But under Windows it informs an error at  4% of building and under RASPBIAN the build informs the same error at 10%.

The error is multiple definition of `main';

testing/util_test.cpp:18: multiple definition of `main';  But this a MACRO.
hello_world_test.cpp:26: first defined here